Next Auth invalidate users with JWT
According to the documentation for Next Auth:

You cannot as easily expire a JSON Web Token - doing so requires
maintaining a server side blocklist of invalid tokens (at least until
they expire) and checking every token against the list every time a
token is presented.

What is the correct way to invalidate a token in Next Auth? The docs don't explain this.
